# Multiple interface devices for KVM bridging

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I have a server that I'm trying to virtualize with KVM. I'm trying to use a network bridge so that my KVM guests can have external IPs. Every time I create a bridge

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
```

It causes eth0 to drop out, which I now know is expected behavior. My first thought to work around this was to give only one IP to eth0, which would be used to control the host server remotely, and put the rest of the IPs in eth1, so a network bridge could enslave eth1 without damaging remote connectivity

Is this a viable solution, or is there a better way to go about this? Whenever I try to add eth1 to /etc/network/interfaces, and then bring the networks down & up, it causes the server to no longer be accessible.

I do have KVM access (the remote access tool) to the server, so I can fix it if things go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure your bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.0.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_maxwait 5
```

Change your ip address / netmask / gateway / etc as needed.

See http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/virt-manager-bridged-networking/ for details.

If you are having a problem, post your configuration files.